# Paired t-test, t-test or chi-sqaure test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test

I want to compare two types of designs. After showing them the images of two designs, I have asked the user (7 questions), which design they like most (A or B)? The user can chose only 1 out of 2 options (A or B).

Example of the data collected is as follows:

```
Sub A   B
1   5   2
2   5   2
3   6   1
4   7   0
5   4   3
6   7   0
7   7   0
8   6   1
9   6   1
10  6   1
11  7   0
12  5   2
13  6   1
14  0   7
15  6   1
16  7   0
17  7   0
18  7   0
19  7   0
20  7   0
21  6   1
22  7   0
23  2   5
24  7   0
25  7   0
26  1   6
27  5   2
28  6   1
29  6   1
30  7   0
```

My options are as follows:

- Can I use a paired t-test to find if there is a significant difference between the two choices?
- Should I use one-sample t-test (e.g. for A, Hypothesised mean = 3.5)?
- Should I go for chi-square test?

Which of the three above options is the best considering the data that I have provided?

Answer (score 1):

Of those three, I would say a paired t-test is best.  But, if it were my analysis, I would use a nonlinear multilevel model with count responses.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your quick response. Is it possible for you to send me some links where I can see the examples of how 'nonlinear multilevel model with count responses' can be applied?

Comment: In R, there is the nlme package.  In SAS there is GLIMMIX.  I don't know other software.  Both of those packages have examples.  These models have been discussed here on CrossValidated.

Comment: A t-test (paired or non-paired) is not at all applicable here, and neither is a Chi-Square test. This is a Binomial (n,p) distribution with n=7 and you are testing for p -  whether p=0.5 or not. An approximation would be a (one-sample, looking only at the A counts) Z-test (rather than a t-test)  in which you are testing if μ=3.5 or not, and the standard deviation is 1.323 (the square root of 7 x 0.5 x 0.5). A sample size of 30 is considered sufficient for the Normal approximation.

Comment: The total under B s simply 7 minus the total under A. What you have then is that the information in each subjects response is entirely contained in the count under A. The result under B is perfectly negatively correlated with it and trying to do a paired test in that situation would seem to be counterproductive. I agree that some kind of model incorporating a random-effect would make sense, though.