# Hypothesis test on binary preference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, chi-squared-test

I have two product designs and I want to see if there is a significant difference between which people like which design the best. I did a survey where I showed a photo of each design and asked questions like:

1. Which one looks better overall?
2. Which design logo do you prefer?
3. Which color scheme do you prefer?

So that I have a table with the following format:

| Questions | Design 1 | Design 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 100 | 200 |
| Question 2 | 80 | 220 |
| Question 3 | 140 | 160 |

Which test should I use to test which design people prefer overall?
I have tried the t-test for independence on the columns, which seemed to fit best. But slight changes already gave low p-values. For example:

| Questions | Design 1 | Design 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 99 | 101 |
| Question 2 | 100 | 100 |
| Question 3 | 98 | 102 |

...gave a p-value of $0.07048399691021993.$

I have also seen chi-squared tests, but I don't know if it is the best test. The final one I am considering is to perform a binomial test on each question to see how much it would differ from simple random sampling.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What do the values in your table represent? Are they counts? For example does Question 1 Design 2 in the first table state that 200 people said they liked it (as in the variable is binary but summed to 200 "yes" responses)? I also agree that this question should be narrowed down to one major question, which I believe is just "which test should I use?"

Comment: Is the total number of participants the result of th addition of the columns "design 1" and "design 2" ?

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the answer to this question would be in line with the discussion on this thread: [Paired t-test, t-test or chi-sqaure test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301375/paired-t-test-t-test-or-chi-sqaure-test?rq=1). So if you have the individual data as well, you can try to make the table by observation (how many times they indicated each design) and do a paired-test to check if one design is preferred more often consistently compared to the other design.

Note: These are options if your distributional assumptions are not violated, otherwise, you might want to use non-parametric alternatives like the Wilcoxon sign test.